# Swift Data() Struct

Tags: swift, utf-8, nsfilemanager

I've been using the Swift class NSFileManager to read files on my MAC and store their contents in the Data() struct.  I've looked at all the methods of this class and cannot find a way to debug the contents of the struct.  When I print(data), I just get the utf8 values of each byte.  I'd like to see the  "character" representation of each byte instead.  I know this will only be relevant for text files read into the Data struct.

Thanks

```
let fileMgr = FileManager.default
var sourceFile = "/tmp/test.pdf"
let databuffer = fileMgr.contents(atPath: sourceFile)
print(databuffer) // this give me the utf8 integer values only
```

Comment: You can initialize a String with Data.

Comment: It's unclear because you say "I'd like to see the "character" representation of each byte instead. I know this will only be relevant for text files read into the Data struct.". So what do you expect really? Any example?

Comment: Yes sorry...if my text file stored the following - "this is an example of a text file".  I want the print(databuffer) to show: this is an example of a text file.   Currently, I'm getting a series of integers that are the UTF8 values of each character (byte).   hope that helps.

Comment: Cyberbeni - x code is throwing an error on this:  ```let bodycontents: String = databuffer
```